# How many points do I need on a sphere to force the minimum distance to be small?

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry, discrete-geometry

Let $\mathbb{S}^2$ denote the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with its standard metric, and let $S\subset\mathbb{S}^2$ be some finite set of points. Given $\varepsilon>0$, how big does $S$ need to be to force the minimum non-zero distance between elements of $S$ to be less than $\varepsilon$?

I don't need to know the absolute minimum size of $S$, I just need to know a number $n_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for any $S\subseteq\mathbb{S}^2$ with $|S|\geq n_\varepsilon$, there are $p,q\in S$ such that $0<d(p,q)<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Said differently, given an $\varepsilon>0$, how many non-overlapping circles of radius $\varepsilon/2$ can you fit on the unit sphere? Also note that the distinction between the distance along $S^2$ and the line distance in $\Bbb R^3$ is almost insignificant for all but the largest $\varepsilon$. At any rate, converting between them is an exercise in elementary trigonometry, and an answer given in either may be applied to the other without too much extra work.

Comment: Do you need a sharp bound? Would it be very bad if you chose $S$ that was $1.5$ times as large as it absolutely needed to be?

Comment: To expand on Arthur and David K's comments, circle and sphere packing problems are notorious for being difficult to solve exactly except by brute force. You are not going to find an exact solution for every $\varepsilon$. Start with one circle, fill around it with additional circles tangent to it. But for most $\varepsilon$, there will be at least one gap. The next round of circles will be crooked because of the gap, and so on. A few more layers and you no longer have anything resembling the nice neat arrangment you started with. That's why you either live with estimates or brute-force it.

Comment: I don't need a sharp bound. Obviously the lower the better, but I have clarified the set up in the question accordingly.

Comment: Do you consider the Euclidean distance or the great arc ?

Comment: Great arc, but see Arthur's comment.

Answer (score 1):

A simple bound can be obtained by noting that if every point is surrounded by a disk of radius $\epsilon$, these cannot wholly cover the sphere as long as

$$S\pi\epsilon^2<4\pi.$$

For small $\epsilon$, the mot compact packing will be hexagonal-like, probably leading to a bound near

$$S=\frac4{\epsilon^2}\frac{2\sqrt3}\pi.$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing

Comment: So are you saying that, if $|S|\geq8\sqrt{3}/\varepsilon^2\pi$, then some of the closed (spherical) discs of radius $\varepsilon/2$ centred on points of $S$ must overlap?